# Android : [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I was earlier using a native library whose `.so` file was kept in the `jniLibs` folder. I then decided to remove the library. So I deleted the `jniLibs` folder and all the references in the code that were pointing to the library.

I removed the `abiFilters` block from my app module's `build.gradle` as well.

Moreover, I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the project. I also explored other StackOverflow answers but all of them provide steps to be taken if a native library **IS** being used.

My Android Studio version is 3.1.2.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: have you try unzipping your apk, then inspect if any native lib folder is still there? even a empty folder with only name  `arm64` would cause app trying to load native libs

Comment: Thanks William, I unzipped the apk and didn't find any folder related to native code.